# How to send Touch tones (DTMF?) with Twilio Softphone

Tags: dtmf

we've successfully setup a Twilio Softphone using their Programable Voice. We need to ability to send key presses to the other party while on the phone with them. For instance, when I call a company the auto attendant asks me to press "1" for sales, "2" for marketing, "3" for support... etc.

How can I send the DTMF tones while on the call with them?

The solutions we've tried:

--- *One option is to use the sendDigits parameter when making your outbound phone call. Specifying sendDigits tells Twilio to dial a set of DTMF tones once your outbound call has connected. This is an example that includes the sendDigits parameter.*---

This "solution" only seems to allow us to send a predetermined set of tones. This is unhelpful because we don't know what tones we will need until we're on the call with the company and need to choose a tone. Why can't we just play a tone during a call like any modern touch tone phone?

--- *Another option is to use the  verb includes a parameter named digits which lets you tell Twilio it should play a set of DTMF tones. This is an example of using  with the digits parameter.* ---

From our experience, we've only been able to get the system to play the sound and then end the call... How can we get the system to simply play the sound in the middle of the call without forcing a transition at the end of the sound? Is there a way to simply play a sound "in-line" just like when I'm on my cellphone with someone I can continue talking with them while pressing keys... we both hear the tones. I can't understand why this seems so hard to implement on a soft phone. *sigh*